# Errors with Tizen IDE and HelloAccessoryProvider

Tags: android, eclipse, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying a sample app for Tizen Wearable SDK but the IDE does not seem to be configured properly. It reports imports could not be resolved library and the samsung android libraries. My guess is these dependencies need to be added to the project's path somehow.

[image]

I tried adding external classes from the Tizen Wearable SDK

[image]

**UPDATE**
I have tried to install the ADT Plugin but I get stuck on the license screen

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the Android plugins for Eclipse installed from what I can see on your preferences panel. The Tizen IDE, out of the box, only supports the Tizen Wearable build.

You will need to install the Android Development Tools (ADT) plugins for Eclipse and then point the preferences at the SDK. That will clear up your Android SDK build errors. Then you just need to add the Samsung SDK jars to your project if they still fail to build. The samples should already have the links to SDK jars in them, so just getting the plugins installed is your first step.

Here's a [blog post](http://samsungdevus.com/blog/develop-samsung-gear-android-apps-tizen-ide-wearable) I wrote on the subject a few months ago. Skip to the TL;DR part. But, the short answer is, add the ADT plugins by adding a new install site that points to

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

You will not be able to install the **Native Development Tools** component due to a conflict with CDT versions, so uncheck that.

Comment: Eric thanks for the blog link but I got stuck on Review License. I have toggled accept not accept several times. Next is still disabled.

Comment: Try downloading the ADT.zip file directly from Google's site. Use the 'archive' button rather than entering a http site to install it into Tizen IDE/Eclipse.   http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

Comment: After your post, I just tried this with a pristine Tizen IDE and ADT.zip on MacBook Pro running Yosemite. When I accept the terms of the license, the "Finish" button will appear. Perhaps extract and install the Tizen SDK again?

Comment: There is something hinky going on here. I was able to get add repo local button to open a dialog but then it would not let me select the ADT.zip so then I restart and I cannot even get that file picker dialog to appear. It does not accept my path when I manually enter it either. I tried installing Tizen from the image. I'll try uninstalling Tizen and reinstalling it the other way which takes a longer time for me.

Comment: Since you seem knowledgable, I was wondering if I can integrate Tizen support into an existing Android project I have that uses Gradle and use the Tizen SDK in Android Studio?

Comment: There are some issues with the Tizen IDE on Mac, specifically around how File dialogs work. There was a bug that was fixed in several years ago, but the Tizen SDK has not integrated a newer version of Eclipse since then. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364116

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Tizen IDE to create the HelloAccessoryConsumer (wearable part) and a separate Eclipse IDE with ADT plugin to create the HelloAccessoryProvider (Android part). Then add the .wgt file which is generated in the HelloAccessoryConsumer project to the assets folder in the HelloAccessoryProvider project.